# Integrating new authentication flow with Keycloak and external IdP using REST API calls instead of SAML

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

How can I add OIDC CIBA based Identity Provider in Keycloak as an alternate authentication provider. Unlike other IdP that redirect the user to their domain for Authentication and then redirect back with token, this particular IdP provides Rest Apis to authenticate the user.

In this flow, when a user tries to authenticate using the provider, they only need to send their User Id to an API call and receive a random number and a transactionId in response. The external IdP then sends a push notification to the user's device, as user accounts are already created on that provider. The next API call is used to poll the status of the request, checking if it has been approved or not (By Selecting that random number). Finally, the third API call retrieves the token if the transaction is approved.

I would like to implement this flow as an alternative authentication method, alongside the existing form-based authentication provided by Keycloak. Do I need to create a custom Identity Provider for this purpose, or are there any out-of-the-box solutions available? It is important that this flow is only triggered if the user chooses to authenticate via this particular IdP, without modifying the browser authentication flow in general.